# Fixing $.mobile.navigate forward history issues?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-store-apps

I am working on a windows 8 application using phonegap. Currently I am using jquery mobile for all the ajax based page navigations in a single html page.

I am using the Jquery mobile 1.4.2 stable release.

Consider that, I have the single page index.html and I have sub pages as #page1, #page2 and #page3 for which I will be making navigation using

```
$.mobile.navigate();
```

In my case, the landing page is index.html (or) index.html#page1 and using $.mobile.navigate("#page2") I traverse to index.html#page2 where my history stack is as follows:

```
Current:ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html#page2
Stack: (active index = 1 -previous index: undefined )
0-ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html
1-ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html#page2
```

and again from here I traverse using $.mobile.navigate("#page3") to index.html#page3 where my history stack will be as follows

```
Current:ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html#page3
Stack: (active index = 2 -previous index: undefined )
0-ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html
1-ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html#page2
2-ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html#page3
```

From there I use window.history.back(); to traverse to index.html#page2 where my history stack will be as follows

```
Current:ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html#page2
Stack: (active index = 1 -previous index: 2 )
0-ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html
1-ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html#page2
2-ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html#page3
```

This is where my **issue** begins. If I try to traverse back to index.html#page3 using $.mobile.navigate("#page3") the history stack gets an appending of new/duplicate entry as follows which collapses the stack

```
Current:ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html#page3
Stack: (active index = 3 -previous index: 2 )
0-ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html
1-ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html#page2
2-ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html#page3
3-ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html#page3
```

So when I traverse back using window.history.back(); the page traverses to index.html#page2 and without any operation it gets traversed to index.html#page1 in a few seconds. The recorded history stack when the page index.html#page2 is visible is as follows

```
Current:ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html
Stack: (active index = 0 -previous index: 1 )
0-ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html
1-ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html#page2
2-ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html#page3
3-ms-appx://9616f46d-1e09-4e01-8e2a-50c58b4967c5/www/index/index.html#page3
```

Is there a way/workaround to fix the above mentioned duplicate appending of entries into history stack and create a consistent set of page navigations?. Or is there a better alternate way of doing page navigations?

Comment: why are you using `$.mobile.navigate();` why dont you use `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "change", "file.html or #page" );`?

Comment: $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "change", "file.html or #page" ) also has some issues. One thing I observe here is that there is no duplicate entries in history stack when I used this but the previous index is not maintained properly. Either it has no or wrong value. Any workaround would be appreciated

Comment: Test it again using browser's back button and an anchor with `data-rel="back"` attribute. Check if both behave the same.

Comment: If I use data-rel="back"..nothing is happening as the previous index is undefined. If I use window.history.back(), the page is getting traversed to the previous page with wrong previous index entries. Any workaround?